# How to fill nan values in a column if the value from another column matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have a dataframe like this one:

```
      col1         col2     col3
0     data1         0        NaN
1     data1         0        NaN
2     data1         1        Done
3     data2         0        NaN
4     data2         1      To be done
5     data3         0        NaN
6     data3         1        Fail
```

How can i replace nan values in col3 for example: data1 in col1 hasa a row in col3 that is 'Done',
how can i pass this value to all NaN rows in col3 which contains data1 in col1?

Desirable df would look like this:

```
      col1         col2      col3
0     data1         0        Done
1     data1         0        Done
2     data1         1        Done
3     data2         0      To be done
4     data2         1      To be done
5     data3         0        Fail
6     data3         1        Fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `bfill`:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].bfill()
print(df)

# Output:
    col1  col2        col3
0  data1     0        Done
1  data1     0        Done
2  data1     1        Done
3  data2     0  To be done
4  data2     1  To be done
5  data3     0        Fail
6  data3     1        Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to create a dict and map it over col1:

```
d = dict(df[pd.notna(df['col3'])][['col1', 'col3']].values)
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(d)
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | data1 | 0 | Done |
| 1 | data1 | 0 | Done |
| 2 | data1 | 1 | Done |
| 3 | data2 | 0 | To be done |
| 4 | data2 | 1 | To be done |
| 5 | data3 | 0 | Fail |
| 6 | data3 | 1 | Fail |

Comment: Hey @ezer, thank you for the answer, maybe because my real dataframe has a lot of columns with NaN values this was not working in my case.

Comment: if you still need it, try my fix